# Unable to open LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice

When I search applications and select LibreOffice, it asks me on the next screen which one to open.  `Calc` works and opens a new spreadsheet but `Writer` does not. My `Ubuntu 14` should be up to date but I can't remember if LibreOffice came with it or I installed it.

How can I enable, or install altogether, the Writer ?

Comment: Please open a terminal window, and try to start writer by entering `libreoffice --writer`, and see if there is some error message that appears on the terminal.

Comment: I do that and it opens `Calc` ... it's so weird as we're clearly supply `--writer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just need to install the [`libreoffice-writer`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libreoffice-writer) package *(parts of libreoffice are available in multiple packages, see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libreoffice&searchon=all))*. This can be done with:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-writer
```

You should also be able to do it via Synaptic, Software Center